# Finch robot. Java

Tags: java, loops

I am currently using loops with the finch robot to test some java codes and have come across an error. Here is my code.

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;

public class CS1702_Lab4 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Finch myf = new Finch();

        myf.setWheelVelocities(100,100);
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();{
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < 5000)
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            if (myf.isTapped()) break;

        }
        myf.stopWheels();
        myf.quit();
    }
}
```

On line "myf.setWheelVelocities(100,100)", I am getting the following error;

- Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
  -Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s).

Any help towards solving this error is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like you mean this - http://www.finchrobot.com/ Wow ! Did not even know that it existed. Getting myself one :)

Answer (score 2):

you have too many brackets `{ }`

remove them in these lines:

```
long before = System.currentTimeMillis();{
```

and here:

```
myf.quit();
 }
```

Also it seems as if you have no class declaration.

```
public class CS1702_Lab4 {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
  {
       Finch myf = new Finch();

       myf.setWheelVelocities(100,100);
       long before = System.currentTimeMillis();

       while(System.currentTimeMillis() - before < 5000)
       {
          Thread.sleep(500);
          if (myf.isTapped()) break;

       }
       myf.stopWheels();
       myf.quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: If i remove the curly bracket on that line, i get an error saying "Syntax error on token";", insert {".

Comment: I can compile it like that. You still have some mistake in your code I guess.

Comment: I think there is simply something wrong with your class declaration. And from that, it appears you only have a basic understanding of classes. So before you start this project, read up a little on how classes in Java works, then copy the code Edgar has to your project.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late now, but this piece of code

```
myf.setWheelVelocities(100,100);
```

should have 3 sets of numbers e.g.

```
myf.setWheelVelocities(100,100,5000);
```